# What are LEGO baseplates made from?

Tags: manufacturing, plastics

I want to lasercut a green LEGO baseplate for a project, but cannot cut a plastic with the laser if it contains PVC or Vinyl.

Does anyone know if the green baseplates are free from these materials.

Comment: I tried to make an abs slurry using pure acetone, using 32x32 tan baseplate, but it didn't dissolve, just a soft bubble gum consistency settled at the bottom of the jar, so I don't think it is pure !

Answer (score 9):

LEGO baseplates are made from ABS plastic, like most of the opaque rigid plastic LEGO elements since 1970. ABS is a thermoplastic consisting of a styrene monomer with the addition of an acrylonitrile momomer and a butadiene monomer. There is no PVC or vinyl present.

I suggest reviewing [this thread](http://www.sawmillcreek.org/showthread.php?90680-ABS-Plastic) for more on laser-cutting ABS. It is not a trivial matter to get a good result.

Edited to add:
In response to a query from a "safe toy" website, LEGO [categorically stated](http://www.safbaby.com/lead-free-pvc-free-and-fire-retardant-free-toy-manufacturers) that they do not use PVC in any of their products except in rare instances like electrical wiring insulation.

Comment: Not all LEGO parts are ABS, far from it; there are 10-20 different material used depending on the usage. As the baseplates are slightly more flexible, I'd wager they are actually not ABS. I don't think PVC or Vinyl have been used at all, though.

Comment: I did not say all Lego parts are ABS; I specifically mentioned "rigid plastic" Lego elements. Obviously I am not counting the molded rubber pieces, the strings, the capes, etc. (I concede that, upon further research, the transparent Lego elements may not be made from ABS.) The baseplates are, in fact, ABS, and they are only more flexible because they are thinner than other Lego elements.


Brickowl thinks they are made of ABS: http://brickowl.com/catalog/lego-baseplate-32-x-32-3811

Comment: Well let me rephrase then: "Not all **rigid** LEGO parts are ABS", and that's why I had doubt about the baseplates. I also believe the molding process of baseplates might be different as well (done in sheets), which may require a different plastic. Granted, your brickowl link is the only indication we have so far, but since they seem to put "ABS" on everything (even [transparent bricks](http://brickowl.com/catalog/lego-transparent-brick-1-x-4-3010) which are known to never be ABS), I'm not too sure I'm willing to trust them either.

Comment: According to https://www.lego.com/en-us/sustainability/product-safety/materials Lego uses HIPS to make baseplates.

Answer (score 1):

They are made from ABS injected into a mold. I actually got to see Legos made at legoland, a truly amazing experience!